# PC processes halt over time

Tags: crash, desktop-computer

So I'm not entirely sure exactly how to title this question, so if there are any suggestions, please let me know and I will revise it.

### Symptoms / Backstory

However, I have a desktop (Specs at the bottom of this post) that is (seemingly) randomly crashing on me. No Blue Screens, no errors. It seems like each process just halts, but doesn't actually die. They just stop. It will start with something active in the foreground like a Chrome tab, though interestingly, I was watching a video on Facebook when it started to buffer, but I could still scroll. I was able to close Chrome, but not reopen it. Then my Windows Background, which uses "Wallpaper Engine" froze. Then I could not open my Start Menu or Task Manager, but my mouse never stopped working, and the keyboard never froze (I could still toggle Caps / Num Lock). After letting it sit, I eventually had to reboot, and it worked again.

Temperatures are all good. Highest Temp I've recorded was about 50c, I think.

### Things I have tried:

- Letting the PC set (over a year)
- Re-seated the CPU and RAM
- Completely re-installed Windows (On a different drive)

### Things I am going to try

I have a set of 4 Corsair Vengeance DDR3 Sticks I'm going to try out in there, and see what happens.

### Other Notes

I have tried googling the issue and doing my own research, but no matter what I look up, I just get all the generic "5 reasons your PC runs slow" kinds of pages that don't actually offer any advice.

Any other details will be added, but I'm not sure what is relevant.

### PC Specs

- ***CPU*** - i7 3770k (Not overclocked, but watercooled)
- ***RAM*** - 16 GB DDR3

  - (2x4GB) PNY XLR8
  - (2x4GB) G.Skill Ripjaws Z
- ***Video Card*** - GeForce 760 (nVidia branded, not Asus or EVGA)
- ***PSU*** - 500W (Cooler Master RS-500-PCAR-D3)

Comment: It could be hardware or software issue, have you tested your RAM using memtest?

Comment: You should try some component stress testing with available software out there. Target one component at a time. For example MemTest86 for your memory, FurMark for your video card, etc.

Comment: I've used 2 completely different sets of hardware, and I tried Intel's CPU test which passed all but one test, but after updating the drivers it seemed to pass everything. I can rule out the Video Card as well, as I used it for several months without any issues.

Comment: How about memory? Memory would be one of the ones I would test first.

Comment: I said hardware above. That was a mistake. What I meant was 2 completely different sets of RAM. The configuration listed above, and then the separate set of Corsair Vengeance RAM. Is there something more specific I can try to rule out the CPU more than the Intel test?

Comment: Usually CPU is very unlikely to be "partially faulty". It usually works or it doesn't. Sounds like it is working fine for you

Comment: Okay, so 2 completely separate sets of RAM, and the same issues... I would then start to think maybe it's the Mobo? There is not much more to the system than what I posted above. 2 SSDs for 2 OSs, and a DVD Burner, and that's it. I guess it could also be the SSD, maybe? (Also, sorry for not being more helpful here. I'm a bit desperate, and not well versed in how things work here, so I am very grateful for the help)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63617/discussion-between-eric-f-and-zlhysong).